# jQuery toggle panels, background change

Tags: jquery, background, toggle, slide

I have a splash page with two buttons "login" and "register".
What I managed to obtain so far playing with the code is:
1. Expand the login and register forms (div) when I click the buttons.
2. Hide the other form if it's already visible (only one form visible at a time and only one button in 'pressed state' at a time).
3. Change the button background when pressed and the respective panel is visible.

And this is the code so far:

```
$(function() {
                $('#login').click(function() {
                    $('.login').slideToggle('fast');
                    $('.register:visible').slideToggle('fast');
                    $("#register").css("background", "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)");
                    $("#login").css("background", "rgba(255,0,0,0.6)");
                    return false;
                });
                $('#register').click(function() {
                    $('.register').slideToggle('fast');
                    $('.login:visible').slideToggle('fast');
                    $("#login").css("background", "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)");
                    $("#register").css("background", "rgba(255,0,0,0.6)");
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

The problem with the code above is that when I hide both panels, one of the buttons keeps a "pressed state" rgba(255,0,0,0.6).. Also I would like to add a hover effect when the buttons are unpressed, how can I do that also?

Thank you very much in advance, I am a newbie with jquery and I'm struggling..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd recommend adding and removing CSS classes rather than directly changing CSS properties - it might clear up some bugs, not sure though: `$('#register').addClass('btnClicked');`

You can add a hover effect like so:

```
$('#login, #register').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('btnHover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('btnHover');
}
```

Of, if you want to keep your style, just put the hovering CSS code in the first function, and revert it to normal in the second function.